# IOS sceneWillEnterForeground Handle Universal links

Tags: ios, swift

In my ios app I have below functions in my SceneDelegate class:

```
func sceneWillEnterForeground(_ scene: UIScene) {
    print("... sceneWillEnterForeground ALWAYS CALLED")
    NotificationCenter.default.post(name: Notification.Name("update"), object: nil) // ONLY TO BE CALLED when universal link is not clicked
}

func scene(_ scene: UIScene, continue userActivity: NSUserActivity) {
    print("SCENE WITH UNIVERSAL LINK CLICK")
    guard let url = userActivity.webpageURL else { return }
    let userInfo: [String: String] = ["url": url.absoluteString]
    NotificationCenter.default.post(name: NSNotification.Name("universalLink"), object: nil, userInfo: userInfo)
}
```

- sceneWillEnterForeground function is always called
- scene(scene:continue:) is called only when universal link is clicked.
- I want `NotificationCenter.default.post(name: Notification.Name("update"), object: nil)`  to only be called when universal link is not clicked.

I tried getting userActivity from scene in sceneWillEnterForeground but no data is present to add any conditional checks. Is there any other function that would be called when universal links is not clicked?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I achieved the desired behavior by using a flag that is set in the scene(_:continue:) function, and then checked in the sceneDidBecomeActive function, which is called after the app has returned to the foreground

```
class SceneDelegate: UIResponder, UIWindowSceneDelegate {

    var isUniversalLinkOpened = false

    func scene(_ scene: UIScene, continue userActivity: NSUserActivity) {
        if let url = userActivity.webpageURL {
            let userInfo: [String: String] = ["url": url.absoluteString]
            NotificationCenter.default.post(name: Notification.Name("universalLink"), object: nil, userInfo: userInfo)
            isUniversalLinkOpened = true
        }
    }

    func sceneDidBecomeActive(_ scene: UIScene) {
        if !isUniversalLinkOpened {
            NotificationCenter.default.post(name: Notification.Name("update"), object: nil)
        }
        isUniversalLinkOpened = false
    }

    // ... other functions ...
}
```